# AWS User Data Script - Dependency Installation Failure

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, terraform, user-data

I have a simple user_data script that I am applying to am aws_launch_template inside of a terraform module.

```
resource "aws_launch_tempalte "host" {
  ...
  user_data = filebase64(".../install_python.sh")
}
```

My starting point was a very simple script that only apply a system update and installed python3 onto the host.

```
#!/bin/bash

dnf update -y
dnf install -y python3
```

My goal is to add additional dependencies (git, docker, kubectl, etc) in a similar fashion, but for some reason, my user data script fails to run at all as soon as I add another command.

For example, if I just append `dnf install -y git` to the above script, it's as if the script fails to run at all. NOTE: the script successfully installs python3 before making this addition.

Question is 1. Why? and 2. What's the best way to view the log output of the user_data scripts via AWS and from within the box itself?

Thanks everyone!

---EDIT---

So I had a list of several dependencies in this script, each install was marked with a comment that explained the justification for each dep. Once I removed the comments, the user_data script executed properly. Any reason why comments throughout the script would interfere?

Comment: Use the [instance console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html).

Comment: Have you checked the user-data logs..?

Comment: where are those located on the host?

Comment: info for that ^ found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html